# Can Python Accept Ctrl+[char] using raw_input?

Tags: python, user-input

I am writing a command line interface in python that accepts a lot of user input. For the values that I am querying the user about, there is a significant amount of "additional information" that I could display, but would rather only display if the user needed help with how to provide a value.

So I thought I would provide my usual `raw_input` prompt, but also try an accept some `Ctrl-H` type sequences to output this help info.

Can Python accept this kind of input via `raw_input` in a terminal/shell? It there another more proper way to do this (preferably in the stdlib)?

Answer (score 0):

No, python cannot accept this kind of input through `raw_input`.  This is because you're thinking about sequences like: `Ctrl-C`, `Ctrl-Z`, etc.  These are not keyboard inputs, these are *signals* that are processed by the **terminal** (not the program).

You can try to set up *signal handlers* that will do this for you, but that is not a very reliable solution (regardless of whether you're using python or something else).

The best solution for accepting this kind of input is to either use **curses**, or use **readline** (with adjustments to the configuration to handle things like `Ctrl-H`).  Using readline will make your life much easier, but it comes with the cost that you have to license your program under the GNU GPL (or similar).  Whereas curses does not have this kind of restriction.

Comment: So I am looking at readline (since you said it would be easier) and I don't see any functions in the docs that seem relevant. Can you expand on what needs to be done?

Comment: @Randy readline has a series of configuration options that control how it reacts to keyboard events (it uses curses for you).  These can be edited by the program to create an interactive environment.  Look into `.inputrc`, this is the file that ordinarily controls the configuration for readline.

Comment: Does this only work in the python interpreter (not that I could get it to work)?

Comment: @Randy This will only work on the on terminal but it should work in any other language/program.